# Minimal system-nspawn container for process tree isolation with embedded applications

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-nspawn

Is it possible to use nspawn for a single executable? My goal is just to isolate the process tree of the application, not portability.

Let's say you wrote an application in C, built for your target platform. Today I am able to run this as a systemd service by configuration via a systemd unit file. Is there a way to make a minimal nspawn "container" for my application? All the articles I've read indicate that nspawn requires debianbootstrap, which ends up being almost 300mb worth of files. If I don't care about portability, is there some other way to leverage the process tree isolation features of nspawn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read through the [systemd-nspawn](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html) man page?  Nothing in there says that you require debianbootstrap, and in fact it shows several non-debian examples.

You *do* a root filesystem, but just like a Docker container (or even a traditional `chroot` environment) that doesn't require anything more than your executable and any shared libraries or other resources necessary for it to run.

If you *just* want process tree isolation, maybe instead of `systemd-nspawn` you want `unshare`:

```
# unshare --pid --fork --mount-proc bash
# ps -fe
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  4 09:49 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root        24     1  0 09:49 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -fe
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into taring up the host OS of the device and try running that via nspawn

Comment: @larsks, do you know if anything similar can help me with this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440722/8305